# Jersey ApplicationEventListener get POST body data

Tags: java, jersey

I have an endpoint handler:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response postForm(MultivaluedMap<String,String> queryParameters) {...}
```

For this application I have an event listener,

```
public class MyListener implements ApplicationEventListener {...}
```

and I need to access the POST request body in `onRequest()`, but the request entity stream is already closed when the execution flow gets to that point. Is there a way to keep the entity stream open and accessible, even after it's been read by endpoint handler?

Comment: Try `requestEvent.getContainerRequest()` -> `cr.bufferEntity()`, `Form form = cr.readEntity(Form.class)` -> `MvMap map = form.asMap()`. You probably don't need to buffer it. I just threw it in there. Doesn't hurt

Comment: @peeskillet: that's the problem... when I call `requestEvent.getContainerRequest().bufferEntity()` it throws IllegalStateException, complaining that entity input stream has already by closed.

Comment: And if you leave out the bufferEntity? Same thing?

Comment: If that doesn't work, you can try to get the form [this way](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/1f4614787c4cfddb5d9177c6c2a663b96ab673cc/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/internal/inject/FormParamValueParamProvider.java#L119)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out calling this before request handling does the trick:

```
requestEvent.getContainerRequest().bufferEntity();
```

Cheers :)